# Android Kotlin IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, kotlin, filtering, indexoutofboundsexception

There are 3-5 items in my array list. I print my array in the console it shows data there but when I try to filter data from my array it shows IndexOutOfBoundsException. Exception show when I try to filter array more than once.

```
println(dataList) // Prints [DataList(id=1, name=ABC),DataList(id=2, name=XYZ), DataList(id=3, name=QWERTY)]
```

But on the next line, if I try to filter items from the array it shows IndexOutOfBoundsException. It shows exception only when I try to filter the array multiple times.

```
view.txtNameOne.text = dataList.filter { it.name== "ABC"}?.get(0).NAME // Works if i comment out bellow line
view.txtNameTwo.text = dataList.filter { it.name == "XYZ"}?.get(0).NAME // Not work if i run both lines
```

I am trying to set TextView value by filtering my array. I don't know what it's causing this exception. I am using this code in Fragment onCreateView method.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

        mDataListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DataListViewModel::class.java) // Fetch Data from Room Database

        var dataList:List<DataList> = mDataListViewModel.getAllData
        println(dataList)
        view.txtNameOne.text = dataList.filter { it.name== "ABC"}?.get(0).NAME // Works if i comment out bellow line
        view.txtNameTwo.text = dataList.filter { it.name == "XYZ"}?.get(0).NAME // Not work if i run both lines

        return view
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the other code in `onCreateView` as well. Also, where do you populate the list? It is better to move the display code to `onViewCreated` as per standard practice.

Comment: It should works fine, It would be good if you can share you full code. So, we have more idea about it.

Comment: I shared my fill oncreateview method. But can you explain why it's giving an error?

Comment: I think there is a waiting issue. When I try to set data in UI using array filter. It may need some time to filter. That is why the exception is showing? Because array prints data in console.

Comment: I tried onViewCreated too. Same thing